# how can I select all rows of a table that match those in another table

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to do something very simple with `data.table` and I lost the idiomatic way to do it

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
DT = data.table(a=sample(letters,1e5,T), b=sample(letters,1e5,T), c=rnorm(1e5))
DT2 = data.table(a=sample(letters,5,T), b=sample(letters,5,T)) 

DT2
   a b
1: k h
2: e v
3: f n
4: m q
5: w v
```

I want to select the rows of `DT` that match those of `DT2`.
As such the number of rows after operation will always be smaller that the initial table.

I want something doing this:

```
> DT[paste(a,b) %chin% DT2[,paste(a,b)]]
     a b          c
  1: m q -0.4974579
  2: e v -0.1325602
  3: w v -1.8081050
  4: m q  0.9025120
  5: w v -0.4958802
 ---               
729: f n  0.5604650
730: f n -1.2607321
731: m q  0.5146013
732: m q -1.8329656
733: k h -0.9752011
> DT2[paste(a,b) %chin% DT[,paste(a,b)]]
   a b
1: e v
2: f n
3: k h
4: m q
5: w v
>
```

Comment: Do you want the first result, or the second?  Or both?  If the latter, those are different questions.

Comment: I want both, or to be reminded why I can't get it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An *inner join* should do:

```
setkey(DT, a, b)[DT2, nomatch=0]
```

Produces:

```
     a b          c
  1: k h -1.6592442
  2: k h  1.1946471
  3: k h -0.8694933
  4: k h  0.7789158
  5: k h -1.3142607
 ---               
729: w v -0.3516787
730: w v  0.5272145
731: w v -0.7531717
732: w v  0.3352228
733: w v  0.1182353
```

If you want to know which values in `DT2` exist in `DT` then:

```
unique(setkey(DT[, .(a, b)], a, b))[DT2, nomatch=0]
```

Comment: @statquant, I updated the answer, but without more details about the error I can't provide additional input.

Comment: Actually if I do `setkey(DT2,a,b)[DT]` I get more than 5 rows... so that's not quite that I updated the question so it is clearer

Comment: @statquant what would you expect?  `DT` is not unique so of course you'll get more than 5 rows.  Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: Is that clearer with the explanation ? I want all rows of the first table that are also in the second table, and drop rows that are not

Comment: @statquant, how is the original answer (after adding `nomatch`) not do what you're asking for?  Note that both your result and the one here have 733 rows, it's just that as a result of the join my result is order as `DT2` is.

Comment: nope, I wanted exactly `unique(setkey(DT[, .(a, b)], a, b))[DT2, nomatch=0]` so something symetrical... which you provided at the end , thanks